# Problem with joint type "continuous" in rviz

Tags: gazebo, joint, rviz, urdf, p2os

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I have this robot model (this is the file p2os_urdf/defs/pioneer3dx.xacro)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="pioneer3dx"
    xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"
    xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"
    xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"
    xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">


  <include filename="$(find p2os_urdf_mod)/defs/pioneer3dx_wheel.xacro"/>
 
  <include filename="$(find p2os_urdf_mod)/defs/erratic_hokuyo_laser.xacro"/>
    


<!-- Chassis -->
    <link name="base_link">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="3.5"/>
            <!--<origin xyz="-0.025 0 -0.223"/>-->
            <origin xyz="-0.05 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                 iyy="1" iyz="0"
                 izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual name="base_visual">
            <origin xyz="-0.045 0 0.148" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
                <mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/chassis.stl"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="ChassisRed">
                <color rgba="0.851 0.0 0.0 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="-0.045 0 0.145" rpy="0 0 0"/>
                <geometry>
                    <box size="0.35 0.25 0.14"/>
                </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="base_link">
        <material value="Gazebo/Red"/>
    </gazebo>

<!-- Top -->
    <link name="top_plate">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.01"/>    
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                 iyy="1" iyz="0"
                izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual name="base_visual">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry name="top_geom">
                <mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/top.stl"/>
            </geometry>

            <material name="TopBlack">
                    <color rgba="0.038 0.038 0.038 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0.0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
                <box size="0.45 0.38 0.01"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="top_plate">
        <material value="Gazebo/Black"/>
    </gazebo>


    <joint name="base_top_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="-0.045 0 0.234" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="top_plate"/>
    </joint>



<!-- Swivel -->
    <link name="swivel">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/> 
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.01" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                 iyy="0.01" iyz="0" izz="0.01"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual name="base_visual">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
                <mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/swivel.stl"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="swivel">
                <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0 0 0"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="swivel">
        <material value="Gazebo/Grey"/>
    </gazebo>


    <joint name="base_swivel_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 0 1"/>
        <anchor xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <limit effort="100" velocity="100" k_velocity="0" />
            <joint_properties damping="0.0" friction="0.0" />
        <origin xyz="-0.185 0 0.055" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="swivel"/>
    </joint>

<!-- Center Wheel + Hubcap -->
    <link name="center_hubcap">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.01"/>    
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.012411765597" ixy="-0.000711733678" ixz="0.00050272983"
                 iyy="0.015218160428" iyz="-0.000004273467" izz="0.011763977943"/>
        </inertial>
    <visual name="base_visual">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
            <mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/center_hubcap.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="swivel">
            <color rgba="0.5 0.5 0.5 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <box size="0 0 0"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    </link>
    <gazebo reference="center_hubcap">
        <material value="Gazebo/Grey"/>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="swivel_hubcap_joint" type="continuous">
        <axis xyz="0 1 0"/>
        <anchor xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <limit effort="100" velocity="100" k_velocity="0" />
        <joint_properties damping="0.0" friction="0.0" />
        <origin xyz="-0.026 0 -0.016" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="swivel"/>
        <child link="center_wheel"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="center_wheel">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.1"/> 
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="0.012411765597" ixy="-0.000711733678" ixz="0.00050272983"
                 iyy="0.015218160428" iyz="-0.000004273467" izz="0.011763977943"/>
        </inertial>
    <visual name="base_visual">
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
            <mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/center_wheel.stl"/>
        </geometry>
        <material name="WheelBlack">
            <color rgba="0.117 0.117 0.117 1"/>
        </material>
    </visual>
    <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${-3.1415927/2.0} 0 0"/>
        <geometry>
            <!--<mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/center_wheel.stl"/>-->
            <cylinder radius="0.0375" length="0.01"/>
        </geometry>
    </collision>
    </link>

    <joint name="center_wheel_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="-0.0035 0 -0.001" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="center_wheel"/>
        <child link="center_hubcap"/>
    </joint>

    <gazebo reference="center_wheel">
        <material value="Gazebo/Black"/>
    <elem key="mu1" value="10.0" />
    <elem key="mu2" value="10.0" />
    <elem key="kp"  value="1000000.0" />
    <elem key="kd"  value="1.0" />
    </gazebo>


<xacro:p3dx_wheel suffix="left" parent="base_link" reflect="1"/>
<xacro:p3dx_wheel suffix="right" parent="base_link" reflect="-1"/>

<xacro:erratic_hokuyo_laser parent="base_link">
    <origin xyz="0.01 0 0.23" rpy="0 0 0" />
</xacro:erratic_hokuyo_laser>

<!-- Front + Back Sonar -->
    <link name="front_sonar">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.0001"/>  
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                 iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual name="base_visual">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
                <mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/front_sonar.stl"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="SonarYellow">
                <color rgba="0.715 0.583 0.210 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0 0 0"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="front_sonar">
        <material value="Gazebo/Yellow"/>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="base_front_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="-0.198 0 0.208" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="front_sonar"/>
    </joint>

    <link name="back_sonar">
        <inertial>
            <mass value="0.0001"/>  
            <origin xyz="0 0 0"/>
            <inertia ixx="1" ixy="0" ixz="0"
                 iyy="1" iyz="0" izz="1"/>
        </inertial>
        <visual name="back_sonar_vis">
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry name="pioneer_geom">
                <mesh filename="package://p2os_urdf/meshes/p3dx_meshes/back_sonar.stl"/>
            </geometry>
            <material name="SonarYellow">
                <color rgba="0.715 0.583 0.210 1.0"/>
            </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0"/>
            <geometry>
                <box size="0 0 0"/>
            </geometry>
        </collision>
    </link>

    <gazebo reference="back_sonar">
        <material value="Gazebo/Yellow"/>
    </gazebo>

    <joint name="base_back_joint" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.109 0 0.209" rpy="0 0 0"/>
        <parent link="base_link"/>
        <child link="back_sonar"/>
    </joint>

  <gazebo>
    <controller:differential_position2d name="controller1">
      <update>100</update>
      <leftJoint>base_right_wheel_joint</leftJoint>
      <rightJoint>base_left_wheel_joint</rightJoint>
      <wheelSeparation>0.39</wheelSeparation>
      <wheelDiameter>0.15</wheelDiameter>
      <torque>5</torque>


      <interface:position name="position_iface_0"/>
    </controller:differential_position2d>

    <controller:gazebo_ros_p3d name="p3d_base_controller" plugin="libgazebo_ros_p3d.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
      <bodyName>base_link</bodyName>
      <topicName>base_pose_ground_truth</topicName>
      <gaussianNoise>0.01</gaussianNoise>
      <frameName>map</frameName>
      <xyzOffsets>0 0 0</xyzOffsets> <!-- initialize odometry for fake localization-->
      <rpyOffsets>0 0 0</rpyOffsets>
      <interface:position name="p3d_base_position"/>
    </controller:gazebo_ros_p3d>

    <!-- this publishes empty joint_states due to no transmission, but
         triggering robot_state_puublisher to publish tf between fixed joints in erratic,
         (e.g. base_laser_link for the base_scan frame) -->
    <controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager" plugin="libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so">
      <alwaysOn>true</alwaysOn>
      <updateRate>1000.0</updateRate>
      <interface:audio name="gazebo_ros_controller_manager_dummy_iface" />
    </controller:gazebo_ros_controller_manager>
  </gazebo>


</robot>
```

When I simulated it in gazebo I can see all the links but if I simulated it in rviz I saw that the two joints of type ***"continuous"*** cause problems, in fact in the tf tree I can't see the ***"swivel"*** frame. It appears if I change the joints type to ***"fixed"***. But obviously to have a correct behaviour in the simulation I need my joints to be continuous.
Any solution to my problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51770/problem-with-joint-type-%22continuous%22-in-rviz/) by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 255 on 2013-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible that I have to specify a transmission for the continuous joints?

---

Originally posted by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) with karma: 255 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you publishing JointState messages corresponding to that joint?

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2013-01-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [camilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/2828/camilla/) on 2013-01-09**:
The joint state should be published automatically by gazebo, but if I do rostopic echo /jointstate the two joints corresponding to the swivel link aren't published.